# No PDA Error from SmsManager

Tags: java, android

I get "No PDA Error" from `SmsManager`.

I guess the problem is somewhere at the `msg Intent`, because without that `setText` command the program works just fine. I get this error since this new intent and the `setText` option.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CompuneActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send_message);        

        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        Intent msg = getIntent();
        String mesaj = msg.getStringExtra("mesaj");
        txtMessage.setText(mesaj);
        //I guess the problem is somewhere here, because without that setText command the program works just fine. I get this no pda error since this new intent and the setText option.

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }    



    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        

        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CompuneActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Se trimite mesajul ...", true);
           ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";


    enter code here
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
    }

    int PICK_CONTACT;
    public void selecteazaContact(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below piece of code wrong. Intent has to to created. look at this example [link](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87)

> ```
>    Intent msg = getIntent();
>     String mesaj = msg.getStringExtra("mesaj");
>     txtMessage.setText(mesaj);
> ```